# css pointer-events property change and respective jquery events not triggering together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iscroll4

Here is my code segment. I am using iscroll 4 for scroll in touch devices and desktop.

```
$('#next_item').bind('mousedown touchstart',function (e) {
        //do something onclick
        $(this).bind('mousemove touchmove',function(e){ //triggers only when i drag over it                 
                dragstart = true;
                $(this).css('pointer-events', 'none');
                myScroll._start(myDown);
                return;                     
        });
});

$('#next_item').bind('mouseup touchend',function (e) {
     if(dragstart) {
        dragstart = false;
        $(this).css('pointer-events', 'auto');
     }
});
```

I have the click event on `#next_item` which does a specific task and also have the drag event on `#next_item` which does different task. Now the problem is when `#next_item` receives drag event the `css pointer-events` is changed to `none` immediately but the drag is not triggering. When i do `mouseup` and then again drag from over `#next_item` then only the drag is triggered. I need the `css pointer-events` to pass drag event to the underlying element. Please suggest if i am doing anything wrong. Without `pointer-events` iscroll gives error while passing the drag event below `#next_item`

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Have you tried jQuery `on` function instead of `bind`. remember this work with jQuery 1.7+ version refer http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Murtaza: I tried using jquery `on` function and jquery 1.7 version. It is working in desktop but could not make it work on ipad or iphone. Can you use `on` function in my code snippet and show me the working.

Comment: hi, please refer this URL you will need to `addEventListener` for touch on ipad or iphone http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-for-ipad-and-iphone/  Hope this solves your problem, if does please let me know will place it as answer so that others can refer.

Comment: @Murtaza: I could not make it work. Can you elaborate by showing it in my code. `mymove` and `mydown` could not figure it out how to use

Answer (score 27):

1. When you want to disable the pointer event for an element with `.css()`:

   ```
   $('#element_id').css('pointer-events','none');
   ```
2. When you want to enable the pointer event for an element with `.css()`:

   ```
   $('#element_id').css('pointer-events','');
   ```

In #1, the element gets disabled and then you cannot access that element.

In #2, the same element gets enabled and you can perform other jQuery operation on it.

Answer (score 4):

I've had better luck using the methods provided with iScroll rather than rolling my own. Specifically, onBeforeScroll and onScrollEnd.

```
var myScroll;

function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('scroller-parent', {
        onBeforeScrollStart: function () {
            $('#scroller').css('opacity',0.5); // just for a visual ref
            return false;
        },
        onScrollEnd: function () {
            alert('done');
            $('#scroller').css('opacity',1);
        }
    });
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);
```

Also, the inclusion of the listeners for touch and the DOM help. Wish I knew exactly what you were trying to do - might be able to show you a better example.

If I'm way off, I'll pull this answer. BTW, jQ 1.6.4 working fine for this answer.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

Include the following `<script>` in your page:

HTML

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#widget').draggable();   // This is required for drag...
      $('#widget').dialog().addTouch();

      // Here you call your functions and perform
      // the functionality for touch and drag...

    });
   </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="widget" style="width:200px; height:200px border:1px solid red" ></div>
</body>
```

It is just an example, as I am completely unaware of what functionality you want from your code snippet. It may not answer your entire question, but this is the logical flow required to solve the problem.